# Integrating JBoss Errai and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, gwt, errai

Errai "rocks" web development using GWT. However I want to leverage on my Spring code base to be used in my web application back-end services.

Service like:

```
@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
 // ...
}
```

Where I can call this service from the GWT UI side, what are the options when I am already using JBoss Errai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the [example](https://community.jboss.org/thread/221062) of how to integrate errai services with spring

Answer (score 0):

1.- You can inject dependencies through some CDI implementation (for JBoss AS it uses Seam).
Or 2.- you can use Seam, to activate the spring application context, if you insist to use spring.

In the first option, you can use some errai archetype to obtain a basic skeleton of an application.
In the second option... you can the same thing, but you have to read about seam-spring context integration.

[Link for the archetype](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ERRAI/Errai+Maven+Archetype)

[Link for spring integration](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/3.1.0.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e12274)